# Duck typing in Go

Tags: interface, go, duck-typing

I want to write a `Join` function that takes arbitrary objects with a `String()` method:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type myint int

func (i myint) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
}

func main() {
    parts := []myint{myint(1), myint(5), myint(6)}
    fmt.Println(Join(parts, ", "))
}

func Join(parts []fmt.Stringer, sep string) string {
    stringParts := make([]string, len(parts))
    for i, part := range(parts) {
        stringParts [i] = part.String()
    }
    return strings.Join(stringParts , sep)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/EhkbyibzHw

`[]myint` cannot be passed to `Join`, because it is not of type `fmt.Stringer`, so I have to write:

```
parts := []fmt.Stringer{myint(1), myint(5), myint(6)}
```

But what if I need `parts` for another operation where the values have to be ints? Should I cast a slice of `myint` to a slice of `Stringer` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Q: Should I cast a slice of `myint` to a slice of `Stringer` then?

There are no casts in Go - only conversions. But conversion from a slice of concrete, non interface type to a slice of interface type is not possible, except by doing it explicitly in a loop. The reason is that, as for example in your case, the `[]myint` backing array has a different memory layout than `[]fmt.Stringer` has. ([Related FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#convert_slice_of_interface))

On a side note, you don't have to write:

```
parts := []myint{myint(1), myint(5), myint(6)}
```

This should work identically:

```
parts := []myint{1, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the Join function to

```
func Join(sep string, parts ...fmt.Stringer) string {
}
```

makes it a lot easier:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type myint int

func (i myint) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
}

type myfloat float32

func (f myfloat) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%0.2f", f)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Join(", ", myint(3), myfloat(3.5543)))
}

func Join(sep string, parts ...fmt.Stringer) string {
    stringParts := make([]string, len(parts))
    for i, part := range parts {
        stringParts[i] = part.String()
    }
    return strings.Join(stringParts, sep)
}
```