# struct String() implemention causes stack overflow with Sprintf "+" flag

Tags: go

Golang noob question:  Why can I *not* use the `"%+v"` flag for a struct in the String() implementation method?

I have a struct where I want to implement a `String()` method for pretty print.  I like the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33252434), but I don't like to type, so I'm trying to modify it to return a string using the `"%+v"` format flag for structs.  from the [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt) doc:

> %v    the value in a default format   when printing structs, the plus flag
>   (%+v) adds field names

This works fine if I simply call it with `fmt.Printf("%+v", color)`, but if I try to put the `+` flag in the `String()` implementation, I get a stack overflow (my first chance to ask a "stack overflow" question on stackoverflow.com ;) )

I'm sure I'm not understanding a pointer reference here, or there is some recursion.  I doubt this noob found my first Golang bug, so can someone please explain?

see go play demonstration here https://play.golang.org/p/13_qI8Iwwa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Package fmt Docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> Except when printed using the verbs `%T` and `%p`, special formatting
>   considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces.
>   In order of application:
>
> 5. If an operand implements method `String() string`, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
>      formatted as required by the verb (if any).
>
> **To avoid recursion in cases such as**
>
> ```
> type X string 
> func (x X) String() string { return Sprintf("<%s>", x) }
> ```
>
> convert the value before recurring:
>
> ```
> func (x X) String() string { return Sprintf("<%s>", string(x)) }
> ```
>
> Infinite recursion can also be triggered by self-referential data
>   structures, such as a slice that contains itself as an element, if
>   that type has a String method. Such pathologies are rare, however, and
>   the package does not protect against them.

---

Inside:

```
func (c Color) String() string {
    // THIS CAUSES STACK OVERFLOW
    return fmt.Sprint(c)
}
```

The call to

```
fmt.Sprint(c)
```

or `fmt.Println(c)`  which calls `func (c Color) String() string` again recursively causes overflow: try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UKlhSlzG8T)

---

Also this works fine: https://play.golang.org/p/NYLtrxUeiA

Comment: Thanks @amd.  Your initial answer pointed out the obvious recursion... But using the new string (`string(x)`) loses the struct reference, so there's still no way to use the "+" flag...   however, your solution in your playground to use the "#" flag in the String() method uses Go's "syntax representation", gives me the labels, and avoids the recursion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the infinite recursion by redefining your type `Color` as a new local type (e.g. `type _Color Color`) and then applying `Sprintf` to the converted value `_Color(color)`, since that cannot recursively call your `String()` function.

```
func (color Color) String() string {
    type _Color Color
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v", _Color(color))
}
```

Note: don't use type aliases (e.g. `type _Color = Color`) because that doesn't introduce a new type, but just introduces a new name for the old type and you're back to that infinite recursion problem.

EDIT: I updated your example accordingly, so you can check that it works: https://go.dev/play/p/Cb1jQTcajc4