# Is there a Go equivalent of PHP's __toString method?

Tags: go

In php exists a `__toString()` method that allow to make a taylored representation of an object. For example:

```
final class Foo
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "custom representation";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo; // this will output "custom representation"
```

In Go it is possible to create a struct:

```
type Person struct {
    surname string
    name    string
}

sensorario := Person{
    "Senso",
    "Rario",
}

fmt.Println(sensorario) // this will output "{Senso Rario}"
```

It is possible to add a toString method to the struct?

---

EDIT:

I've found this solution:

```
func (p *Person) toString() string {
    return p.surname + " " + p.name
}

fmt.Println(simone.toString())
```

But what I am looking for, is the way to replace

```
fmt.Println(simone.toString())
```

with

```
fmt.Println(simone)
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247979/1140971

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/eZFdOkRM17

Comment: wow, exactly!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface.

```
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}
```

Any type that implements this interface will be automatically stringified using it by many different libraries, obviously including the `fmt` package, and will indeed work in your example of `fmt.Println`.

Comment: Very very helpful response. Thank you sir!