# Print list of fields in struct with delimiter

Tags: string, go, struct

I have a type with three fields

```golang
type Person struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Age       int
}
```

Creating an instance and using default `fmt.Sprint()` returns `{John Smith 45}`. However for my use case I need a string of format `John, Smith, 45`. A comma delimited list without being surrounded by curly braces. Is there a more reusable and effective way than:

```golang
fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s, %d", x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Age)
```

I will be using this method alot with other types and I would prefer a generic method rather than having to type out a format for each type I use:

```golang
func asFields(data interface{}) string {
    // TODO logic here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That exact format is not supported by verbs of the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package.

The closest would be

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%#v", p)
```

Which generates a string like:

```
main.Person{FirstName:"John", LastName:"Smith", Age:45}
```

If you exactly need what you posted in the question, you may use reflection to iterate over the fields and build the result like this:

```
func asFields(data interface{}) string {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    b := &strings.Builder{}
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            b.WriteString(", ")
        }
        b.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(v.Field(i).Interface()))
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

This indeed gives:

```
John, Smith, 45
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hhQmLnLCeNr).

Note that this `asFields()` function handles all struct types of course not just your `Person`. Adjustment would be needed to handle pointers and struct of structs of course.

Also note that alternatively to [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint) you may also use [`fmt.Fprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint) directed to the buffer in which we're assembling the string:

```
func asFields(data interface{}) string {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    b := &strings.Builder{}
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            b.WriteString(", ")
        }
        fmt.Fprint(b, v.Field(i).Interface())
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

Which of course gives the same result (and may or may not be faster, benchmark it). Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nu5n4itziAB).

Comment: Also note that it incurs the cost of reflection and will be slower than the static solution that OP is already using.

Answer (score 2):

Can we use this approach, it will be applicable only to `Person type struct` though ?

https://play.golang.org/p/YI2Nu0q51ls

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Age       int
}

func (p Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s, %d", p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Age)
}

func main() {
    p := Person{FirstName: "John",LastName: "Doe", Age: 25}
    fmt.Printf("%v", p)
}
```

Output:

```
John, Doe, 25
```

Similar SO question:
[ToString() function in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247644/tostring-function-in-go)

Comment: The power of interfaces. This is easier and cleaner than doing it with reflect .